# Merging sets of polygon from adjacent image tiles

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two geodataframes that describes objects in two adjacent tiles. I would like to merge these two dataframes so that I can obtain a single dataframe that contains all the polygons. Using the `overlay` command I was able to get a dataframe that describes all the polygons however it did not merge the other fields. To elaborate:

P1:

```
       class     obj_id             geometry
0        0      tile_2200-3000_0    POLYGON ((543390.601 3685451.895, 543335.035 3...
1        0      tile_2200-3000_1    POLYGON ((543296.328 3685553.378, 543266.931 3...
2        0      tile_2200-3000_2    POLYGON ((543405.571 3685445.190, 543408.318 3...
```

P2:

```
        class      obj_id            geometry
0        0      tile_2200-3800_0    POLYGON ((543538.995 3685280.603, 543501.395 3...
1        0      tile_2200-3800_1    POLYGON ((543380.903 3685353.924, 543382.869 3...
```

Overlaying P1 and P2 ( via `geopandas.overlay(p1, p2, how="union")`)

```
       class_1         obj_id_1          class_2    obj_id_2             geometry
0        0          tile_2200-3000_0        NaN        NaN           POLYGON ((543390.601 3685451.895, 543335.035 3...
1        0          tile_2200-3000_1        NaN        NaN           POLYGON ((543296.328 3685553.378, 543266.931 3...
2        0          tile_2200-3000_2        NaN        NaN           POLYGON ((543405.571 3685445.190, 543408.318 3...
3        NaN        NaN                      0     tile_2200-3800_0  POLYGON ((543538.995 3685280.603, 543501.395 3...
4        NaN        NaN                      0     tile_2200-3800_1  POLYGON ((543380.903 3685353.924, 543382.869 3...
```

The overlayed result looks fine, but the class and obj_id columns were not merged. Per the documentation located [here](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html) about union overlays, I understand this is the expected behaviour, but I would like the merged geodataframe to have a single field for class and obj_id. This way I would be able to easily filter through objects of a specific class while viewing on QGIS.

How can I go about achieving this?

There might be a better way to do this merge process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overlay, I just needed to concat the dataframes using pandas as follows:

`geopandas.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat( gpdlist, ignore_index=True), crs=gpds[0].crs)`

This creates a geodataframe as I expect:

```
       class        obj_id              geometry
0        0      tile_2200-3000_0    POLYGON ((543390.601 3685451.895, 543335.035 3...
1        0      tile_2200-3000_1    POLYGON ((543296.328 3685553.378, 543266.931 3...
2        0      tile_2200-3000_2    POLYGON ((543405.571 3685445.190, 543408.318 3...
3        0      tile_2200-3800_0    POLYGON ((543538.995 3685280.603, 543501.395 3...
4        0      tile_2200-3800_1    POLYGON ((543380.903 3685353.924, 543382.869 3...
```